# how to move watermark image to folder in php

Tags: php, watermark

i have created dynamic  watermark image  when user uploads using php, images are also displaying , but the problem is i don't know how to move  the images into particular folder in my site

```
$path=JPATH_SITE.'/media/truematrimony/watermark-K'.$id.'_pho_2.jpg';   
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_multi2"]["tmp_name"],$path);
$font_path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/templates/srinivasmatrimony/font/GeosansLight.ttf'; 
$card = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
$font_med = 12;
$white = imagecolorallocate($card, 0, 0, 0);
imagettftext($card, $font_lrg, , 40, , $white,    $font_path,"kongumarriage.com");
$filenametemp= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/media/truematrimony/watermark- K'.$id.'_pho_2.jpg';
imagejpeg($card, $filenametemp); 
$ImageData = file_get_contents($filenametemp); 
$ImageDataEnc = base64_encode($ImageData); 
unlink($filenametemp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function

```
move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )

$filename - name of the file to move
$destination = folder where you want to move
```